# String Crudos por lectura de teclado en c++

Tags: c++, string

En c++ sé que la lectura de caracteres en crudo (raw string) se hace con R"(string_a_leer)".
`... #include <string> ... string = R"(string_a_leer)"; std::cout<<"Lectura de un string "<<string<<endl; ...`

Pero si lo quiero hacer desde el teclado ya no me vale ponerle el R"()"

`... #include <string> ... std::cout<<"Lectura de un string "<<string<<endl; std::cin>>string; ...`

Estoy empleando windows y lo necesito para introducir la dirección los archivos al tener problema con el caracter escapante "...\User...". He solucionado el problema cambiandole \ por /, pero sigo con la duda si es posible leer directamente desde el teclado un raw string.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El prefijo `R`, según la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) sirve para:

> Raw string literal. Used to avoid escaping of any character. Anything between the delimiters becomes part of the string

Es decir:

> String literal crudo. Usado para evitar que se escapen caracteres. Todo lo que haya entre los delimitadores forma parte del string.

Esto significa que el prefijo `R` únicamente sirve para strings escritos literalmente en el código. Es decir, este prefijo permite que el *compilador* no interprete la secuencia `\n` como un salto de línea. Cuando la secuencia se introduce por línea de comandos, entonces el compilador ahí ya no pinta nada.

puedes hacer la [prueba](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JjDaZEnlLSx7B4w6). En el siguiente código puedes introducir secuencias de escape sin problema en la consola, que dicha secuencia se va a interpretar como un string literal

```
std::string data;
std::cin >> data;
std::cout << data;
```